# Чи підтримується педантизм на ukrainian.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, rules, quality-content

Неодноразово зустрічав надмірну [педантичність](http://promog.org.ua/shho-take-pedantizm/) ([педант](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82)) в дотриманні правил ukrainian.stackexchange.com.

Один із прикладів тут: [chizh:...це запитання є opinion-based](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/899/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE).

Мова - це ж не математика , тут не завжди 2+2 має дорівнювати 4, а будь-яка відповідь по суті є "opinion-based". Посилання на інші сторінки - теж, певною мірою, чиїсь думки. Виходить, що одним лише "opinion-based" можна "завалити" будь-яку статтю.
Крім того, можна будь-який художній прийом визнати за порушення правил:

- епітети і порівняння - "opinion-based";
- алегорія - "rant in disguise";
- гіпербола - "appeal to fear"  ...

Тож, чи дозволяється проявляти творчість і використовувати [художні засоби](http://znoclub.com/mova-ta-literatura/551-khudozhni-zasobi-literaturi-tablitsi.html) української мови на ukrainian.stackexchange.com, чи дозволяється лише офіційний, педантичний стиль викладення?

Comment: Уточніть, будь ласка, що са́ме ви маєте на увазі. Я не зрозумів, як пов'язані (1) «підтримується педантизм», (2) коментар Chizh стосовно opinion-based, (3) використання літературної мови (а якої ще?). І розкрийте значення «надмірної педантичності», будь ласка, аби ми не вгадували.

Comment: @bytebuster: під "надмірною педантичністю" я розумію наступне: "Хочеш, щоб робота зупинилася - роби все строго за правилами" (не знаю хто автор)

Comment: @bytebuster: коментар Chizh стосовно opinion-based - один із проявів педантизму

Comment: Ось ця цитата Chizh'а із чата взагалі "перлина": **"... 1. ось іcнує множина можливих перекладів S яка є підмножиною віх можливих словосполучень U, 2. ось наші оцінки для s є S: F(s) - точності передачі сенсу, G(s) - (напів-)римованості. За допомогою цих оцінок ми і вибирали S з U. 3. якщо нам пощастить ми побачимо, що існує під-множина Z <- S, яка є парето-оптимальною для даних F(z), G(z): z є Z. Але 4. оцінки F(s) та G(s) - є суб'єктивними і 5. пріорітет таких оцінок теж суб'єктивний. В наслідок цього 4а - розглянута нами множина S - неповна, 5а ми не зможемо домовитися, що вибрати з Z»**

Comment: Я не маю нічого проти Chizh'а (просто кинулося в очі) та інших користувачів, але хотів показати, що це сайт про мову, тому потрібно підтримувати творчі рішення, а не спонукати користувачів до тупого копіювання посилань

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko зверніть увагу, що _свою_ перлину я написав в коментар, де їй і є саме місце, а не став писати у вигляді запитання :)

Comment: "Хочеш, щоб робота зупинилася - роби все строго за правилами" - як на вашу думку з цим співвідноситься гіпотетична загальна вимога писати тут виключно згідно норма чинного правопису?

Comment: @chizh: я не мав наміру обговорювати конткретно ваші коментарі, а навів їх лише для прикладу

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko але просто наводячи як приклад, ви все ж не втрималися від пейоративу :)

Comment: @chizh: щодо вимоги дотримання чинного правопису: 1.Я не закликав його порушувати; 2. Взагалі, я мав на увазі правила роботи stackexchange. 3 Правопису ця теза особливо не стосується, бо він вже досить "відпрацьований", а от роботу молодих і невідлагоджених систем, якою на даний момент є ukrainian.stackexchange.com можна легко паралізувати беззастережно дотримуючись правил. Керуючись лише формальними правилами сайту, можна прибрати майже всі повідомлення з цього сайту і не дозволити появу нових

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko тут  мені здається, ви знову вдаєтеся до appeal to fear, буцімто, на Ukrainian.SE, якщо не засудити як ви висловилися "педантизм", чекає не дуже солодке майбутнє. Ні це не так. Ніхто нікого не змушує "**беззастережно** дотримуватися правил". Ukrainian.SE - це в першу чергу люди, а не система, тому ризики лежать всеж поза дотриманням формальних правил: чи то спільноти, чи то того чи _иньшого_ правопису

Comment: @chizh: а мені здається що ваше судження "opinion-based":))) 1. Де ви бачили заклик до засудження? 2. Де ви бачили тезу, що хтось когось примушує? 3. Я виклав своє бачення ситуації, намагався зробити це якомога делікатніше. Якщо ви не вловили хід моїх думок чи не погоджуєтесь з ними, будь ласка, "Down+Close" - я ж залишаюсь при своїй думці

Comment: _роботу молодих і невідлагоджених систем, якою на даний момент є ukrainian.stackexchange.com можна легко паралізувати беззастережно дотримуючись правил_ - мені здається тут ви аппелюєте до майбутніх, негативних наслідків. досить безпідставно, НМД. І якщо це _художній прийом_, то для чого тоді він?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не упевнений, що правильно зрозумів запитання, але:

1. StackExchange, взагалі, і Ukr.SE, зокрема, значно відрізняються від соцмереж. Це місце, куди люди ходять за знаннями. **We Are Here To Learn.**
2. Більшість людей, для яких ми створюємо контент, навіть не реєструються на SE. Вони приходять із Ґуґла/Бінґа, читають те, заради чого їх привів пошуковик, і йдуть геть.
3. Ці люди різні. Одні — патлаті розгільдяї в рваних джинсах (як я був колись), інші — поважні люди у строгому вбранні.
4. Усіх їх об'єднує лише тематика мови. І наша мета — надати знання кожному з них. **Якісне знання**, причому **у тій формі, яку усі ці люди сприймуть**.
5. Така форма існує одна: максимально офіційна.
6. Є безліч [винятків](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454), коли *«художні засоби»* мають сенс, але у будь-якому випадку:

   1. [Be Nice](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).
   2. [Ще раз, Be Nice](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).
   3. [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Answer (score 3):

Насправді, поки не втрутився модератор (а він не повинен в такому випадку втручатися), вирішувати чи є це питання opinion-based будуть учасники спільноти з необхідним (достатньо високим) рівнем репутації. Якщо набереться п'ять голосів - питання буде закрито автоматично.

У когось підхід більш формальний, у когось - менш формальний, але колегіальне рішення повинне вийти більш-менш поміркованим.